# GN density with weight map too thin

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting

I have a GN setup with a collection Info of 3 objects to be displayed on a plane.  The objects are small and I want them to be fairly close together.  I have a weight map to control the distribution.  The parts of the weight map that are full on RED don't have the objects dense enough for my desired output.  Should I give up on the weight map and just use the density?  The issue is I only want my collection objects in a certain part of the plane, NOT everywhere.  It's like I want a controllable density and a weight map.[image][image]

Comment: A VG is a 0,1 range thing.  A density field is not.  Run your density through a map range node or a math/multiply node to make it bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plug the weight map on the *Selection* socket of the `Distribute Points on Faces` node, or the *Selection* socket of the `Instance on Points` node. This way you can adjust the density independently.

The result is slightly different depending on the socket you choose.

`Distribute Points on Faces`
[image]

`Instance on Points`
[image]